# Is there a shorter way of writing this code?

Tags: python

I'd wanna know if there's any shorter way of writing the code below.

```
if l[0] == g and l[1] == g and l[2] == g or l[3] == g and l[4] == g and l[5] == g or l[6] == g and l[7] == g and l[8] == g or l[0] == g and l[3] == g and l[6] == g or l[1] == g and l[4] == g and l[7] == g or l[2] == g and l[5] == g and l[8] == g or l[0] == g and l[4] == g and l[8] == g or l[2] == g and l[4] == g and l[6] == g:
```

I've already tried this:

```
if (l[0] and l[1] and l[2] or l[3] and l[4] and l[5] or l[6] and l[7] and l[8] or l[0] and l[3] and l[6] or l[1] and l[4] and l[7] or l[2] and l[5] and l[8] or l[0] and l[4] and l[8] or l[2] and l[4] and l[6]) == g:
```

And this:

```
if g in (l[0] and l[1] and l[2] or l[3] and l[4] and l[5] or l[6] and l[7] and l[8] or l[0] and l[3] and l[6] or l[1] and l[4] and l[7] or l[2] and l[5] and l[8] or l[0] and l[4] and l[8] or l[2] and l[4] and l[6]):
```

But it's not working.

Comment: you can use dictionary

Comment: you can try ` (l[1]== g and (l[2]== g or l[3]== g) and l[4]== g)`

Comment: @Shijith That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: that seems to be a bad design ....

Comment: @Pascu22 can you explain what you are trying to do? I'm sorry but your code is ridiculously hard to read

Comment: There's *gotta* be a saner approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve with this…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correct, you're checking if any of the sub-lists with pre-definded indices consists of the value `g`. First you can extract the indices groups:

```
indices = [
    (0, 1, 2),
    (3, 4, 5),
    ... # etc
    (2, 4, 6)
]
```

Then check them in a loop:

```
for ix in indices:
    if all(l[i] == g for i in ix):
        return True
return False
```

If you actually need to check *all* the triples, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) instead of hard-coding the indices:

```
for sub in itertools.combinations(l, 3):
    if all(x == g for x in sub):
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your modified `if`-tests

```
l[0] and l[1] and l[2]
```

is that you want to combine the *truth-value* of the tests, but what this code does is `and` your 3 values together, throwing away 2 of them. This conversion happens *before* the `==`. If the first 3 elements of `l` are 1, 3, 5 then the result of your `and` expression will be 5, and so that is what will be compared with `g` (and not some superposition of 1, 3 and 5 that you can then use with `==`).

Your code does rather look as though there is a structure to the data that you have reduced to a flat list, and because the data no longer reflects its intention, the `if`-test is hard to read (and, I suspect, even harder to get right).

By *structure*, I mean that your code is checking a bunch of triplets and the indexes appear to be 1, 2, 3 or 4 apart. But that pattern has been abstracted out and reduced to meaningless numbers.

@bereal's suggestion to pull out the indexes into an explicit list is hard to better. I would only add, if these indexes have more meaning than simply position in the list, consider creating constants (or an `enum` subclass) to say what each index (or the starting point of each triplet) means.